# C# - Make UI function during like a infinite loop until button pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

i make a code in C# where i extract some records from an Access database , but i need the while going to the next iteration to depend on the click of a button. i tried with some Thread or Tasks , but it didn't worked because it blocked the UI which i need it to be seen and clickable.

Here's the code:

```
    bool nextClick = false ;

                while (readerSelect.Read())
                {

                    // show the correct panel
                    if (string.Compare(readerSelect[2].ToString(), "P1") == 0)
                    {
                        // panel with type 1
                        textBoxP1Text1.Text = readerSelect[3].ToString();
                        textBoxP1Text2.Text = readerSelect[4].ToString();
                        pictureBoxP1Image.ImageLocation = readerSelect[6].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // panel with type 2
                        textBoxP1Text2.Text = readerSelect[5].ToString();
                    }

    //this while need to be kind of infinite so the interation can't be processed and 
   //so when i need to change iteration i click the buttonNext 
                    while (!nextClick) {
                    startWhile:; 
                       MethodInvoker mi = delegate () {
                           if (nextClick)
                           {
                               Application.DoEvents(); 
                              // System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
                           }

                        };
                        this.Invoke(mi);
                        //break;
                        goto startWhile; 
                    }

 private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // click on the next button
        nextClick = true; 
    }
```

Comment: If you need to only go to the next item after a click then don't use a while loop... just do one on each click...

Comment: This will have a major impact on our connection which is kind of poor, but thanks for answering

Comment: What do you mean a 'major impact on your connection'?? That is just incorrect. The way you are doing it now and this way will only ever read how ever many records there are. You are mistaken. I would advise reading up on the DataReader documentation until you understand it better as a first point

Comment: The *very* easiest thing to do is to substitute that whole block with `while(!nextClick) {Application.DoEvents();} nextClick = false;`  It'll work, but also result in a tight loop with high CPU doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Dax Fohl's answer works, it seems like you've got a problem in your design.  I think you're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by having too much business logic going on in the `Form` class.

I'd recommend factoring out the business logic into its own class.  Then rather than running through everything in a loop, you simply have the button click event process the next record and display the result.  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();

    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.buttonNext.Enabled = false;
        this.ProcessNext();
    }

    private async void ProcessNext()
    {
        string s = await this.dataProcessor.ProcessNext();
        this.textBoxP1Text1.Text = s;
        this.buttonNext.Enabled = true;
    }
}

public class DataProcessor
{
    private readonly Random r = new Random(); // Or reader or whatever.

    public async Task<string> ProcessNext() // Just using `string` as an example.
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return this.r.Next().ToString();
    }
}
```

I think this will be easier to understand and more maintainable in the future.  When a new team member looks at semaphore stuff (or your future self), it'll be hard to understand/remember what the point of all that was.  Here, you just have a local function that does one thing and is easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a semaphore within an async task, have the button `Release` it during each click, and have the while loop await it each time through.  Here's a quick example, using a form that has a `button1` and a `label1` added to it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, int.MaxValue);

    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.RunLoop();
    }

    private async void RunLoop()
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            this.label2.Text = $"Enqueued: {this.signal.CurrentCount}";
            await this.signal.WaitAsync(); // Wait button click async
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate work
            this.label1.Text = $"Completed: {++i}";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.signal.Release();
        this.label2.Text = $"Enqueued: {this.signal.CurrentCount + 1}";
        // Or if you want to limit the # people can queue up, then put this whole
        // thing in an `if (signal.CurrentCount < myLimit)` block, and optionally
        // disable the button once limit has been reached, and re-enable it right
        // before the `WaitAsync` call above.
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this likely to cause a SemaphoreFullException if the user clicks multiple times while the run loop completes? I'd have thought one of the EventWaitHandle classes would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MartinBrown Yes, just updated answer to account for that.

Comment: @matteomaggioni FWIW I just noticed lobsterism's answer, and do agree with the sentiments expressed there.  While that answer doesn't answer your specific question, I think it is likely a better approach.